# How can i create a class with a property for each country and it's items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of the class

```
public class Country
        {
            public string country { get; set; }
        }
```

And how i build the links

```
public void ImagesLinks()
        {
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                int cnt = 0;
                foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes)
                {
                    imagesUrls.Add(countriesnames[counter]);
                    counter++; 
                    cnt++;
                    for (; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++)
                    {
                        string imageUrlIrTrue = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
                        string imageUrlIrFalse = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "false";
                        imagesUrls.Add(imageUrlIrTrue);
                        imagesUrls.Add(imageUrlIrFalse);
                        if (cnt % 10 == 0)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string myerr = err.ToString();
            }
        }
```

What i have in the end is a List with names and the links of each name.
For example in the index 0 i have the name: Europe
Then then ext 18 indexs are links of Europe

Then the next name is in index 21: Alps
And then the next 18 indxs of Alps

What i want to do is using the class Country is when i will type for example:

Country. ( After the point i will have properties of all the names Europe ,Alps and so on so i can select one of the names ) Same like if i will type for example File. so after the point i will have properties like Create Copy and so on so when i will type Country i will have all the countries names Europe, Alps....
And then if i will make a loop over one of the names it will loop over it's 18 items. For example:

```
For (int i = 0; i < Country.Europe; i++)
{
  // something to do with Country.Europe[i]
}
```

Or

```
For (int i = 0; i < Country.Alps; i++)
    {
      // something to do with Country.Alps[i]
    }
```

So maybe each name/country should be a List of it self ?

```
For (int i = 0; i < Country.Europe.Count(); i++)
    {
      // something to do with Country.Europe[i]
    }
```

But the idea is that i will be able easy to select a name from a properties list and when loop over the name it will loop over it's 18 items.

Comment: Is imageUrls a global list?  I think it's probably better suited as a class property, that way you only store imageUrls for Europe in the List inside of the Europe class, and imageUrls for Alps in the Alps class.  When you need to iterate, you don't need any logic to determine if it's a Europe or Alps imageUrl.  If you need the Europe ones, iterate the Europe list, if you need the Alps, iterate the Alps list...  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think you should manage your data inside enum structure

Comment: @Aaron imagesUrls is global and List<string>

Comment: It's not working good i mean i didn't do something right in my code it's getting the links of the same country all the time. Should i open a new question about it ?

Comment: It probably just has to do with where you're instantiating your country.  Something like: "foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes){ Country cnt = new Country; country.name = countryCode; List<string imageURLs = new List<string>(); for(; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++){imageURLs.Add(xxx);} //back outside of loop cnt.imageURLs = imageURLs}}.  
You just need to figure out how to get it into the setup right.  It'll work once it is.

Comment: It's now working. I will have to test it some more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw this together real fast - it is how I would probably handle it.  I added a little more, I think you just need a class to handle countries.  In any case, you would need to adjust your loop to create this structure, so this isn't a perfect solution - but it's how I would do it.  You could also use linq instead of loops, I did this more as a class-based answer than a "pretty" answer.

```
namespace classTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        World newWorld = new World();

        Continent Europe = new Continent();
        Europe.name = "Europe";

        Country England = new Country();
        England.name = "England";
        List<string> imageUrl = new List<string>();
        imageUrl.Add("url1-England");
        imageUrl.Add("url2-England");
        imageUrl.Add("url3-England");
        England.imageUrls = imageUrl;

        Europe.countries.Add(England);

        newWorld.continents.Add(Europe);

        Country France = new Country();
        France.name = "France";
        imageUrl = new List<string>();
        imageUrl.Add("url1-France");
        imageUrl.Add("url2-France");
        imageUrl.Add("url3-France");
        France.imageUrls = imageUrl;

        Europe.countries.Add(France);
        foreach (Continent continent in newWorld.continents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(continent.name);
            foreach (Country country in continent.countries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(country.name);
                foreach(string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class World
{
    public List<Continent> continents;

    public World()
    {
        continents = new List<Continent>();
    }
}
public class Continent
{
    public string name;
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }

    public Continent()
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        countries = new List<Country>();
    }
}
public class Country
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> imageUrls { get; set; }
    public Country()
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        imageUrls = new List<string>();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution, I use an outer wrapper `Country` that provides static references to instances for the continents (e.g. `Europe`). The continents implement `IEnumerable`, so you can iterate over all countries of this continent or use LINQ to filter them.

```
public class CountryData : IEquatable<CountryData>{
    public string Link { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CountryData other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(Link, other.Link);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Link.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public static class Country {
    public static readonly Europe Europe = new Europe();
}

public class Europe : IEnumerable<CountryData> {
    private List<CountryData> All => new List<CountryData> {
        Austria,
        Belgium
    };

    public CountryData Austria = new CountryData { Link = @"\Country\Austria" };
    public CountryData Belgium = new CountryData { Link = @"\Country\Belgium" };

    IEnumerator<CountryData> IEnumerable<CountryData>.GetEnumerator() {
        return All.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return All.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
var austria = Country.Europe.Austria;
var belgium = Country.Europe.Single(c => c.Link.Contains("Belgium"));

foreach (var european in Country.Europe) {
    Console.WriteLine(european.Link);
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to compare countries, `CountryData` must implement `IEquatable<CountryData>`

Usage example:

```
var isSame = Country.Europe.Austria == Country.Europe.Belgium;
// isSame is false
```